# How to make the functions available  in clisp REPL?

Tags: clisp

Using ~/.guile, the functions in money.scm are available automatically in guile REPL.

```
>cat ~/.guile 
(use-modules (ice-9 readline))
(activate-readline)

;(load "money.scm")
;(use-modules (money))
```

then how can i config the clisp REPL ?

BTW,

are there any "http://try-clojure.org/" similar site ?

Sincerely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GNU Common Lisp [man page](http://www.gnu.org/s/clisp/impnotes/clisp.html#opt-norc):

> Normally CLISP loads the user “run control” (RC) file on startup (this happens after the -C option is processed). The file loaded is .clisprc.lisp or .clisprc.fas in the home directory USER-HOMEDIR-PATHNAME, whichever is newer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to specify the clisp implementation to which you are referring...just in case I answered the wrong question.

Comment: As far as a web-based REPL, I have seen [BioBike](http://nostoc.stanford.edu/Docs/demointro.html), which allows you to log in anonymously and appears to have a full-on common lisp implementation.  It could be useful for testing code snippets and syntax.

Comment: I am using GNU CLISP 2.49 (2010-07-07).  All of your answers are VERY hepful.